# What is this PHP code in VB.net

Tags: php, vb.net

I am looking for the vb.net equivalent of this function: I have no experience of PHP but came across this code which apparently gives you a random image url from google images

```
    function GetRandomImageURL($topic='', $min=0, $max=100)
{
  // get random image from Google
  if ($topic=='') $topic='image';
  $ofs=mt_rand($min, $max);
  $geturl='http://www.google.ca/images?q=' . $topic . '&start=' . $ofs . '&gbv=1';
  $data=file_get_contents($geturl);

  $f1='<div id="center_col">';
  $f2='<a href="/imgres?imgurl=';
  $f3='&amp;imgrefurl=';

  $pos1=strpos($data, $f1)+strlen($f1);
  if ($pos1==FALSE) return FALSE;
  $pos2=strpos($data, $f2, $pos1)+strlen($f2);
  if ($pos2==FALSE) return FALSE;
  $pos3=strpos($data, $f3, $pos2);
  if ($pos3==FALSE) return FALSE;
  return substr($data, $pos2, $pos3-$pos2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its mostly string manipulation, building up the image url. It picks a pseudo random image between index `0` and `100` on this line

```
$ofs=mt_rand($min, $max);
```

The same can be achieved with the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx#Y116) class in .Net

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim ofs As Int = rnd.Next(min, max)
```

I leave the string manipulation to the OP but its probably better to do it with the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, or perhaps one `String.Format`.

It worth considering if the `0` to `100` bounds are overly abritary.